# Open Bootstrap Popup Model without Previous Input Data

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, model, popup

Hi in my Project i am Using bootstrap popup model for Login/Sign Up functionality 
but at the time of opening model it opens with previously input data or Validation [image]

i want to open fresh new model each time at the time of opening model please give me suggestion

[image]

Comment: please provide your popup code as well..

Comment: how to signin and signup using this model. using ajax or something else.

Answer (score 0):

If you are opening the popup on button click, you can try using below code
This code will clear the value of username and password fields before opening the modal popup.

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('#user_name').val('');
    $('#password').val('');
    $('#popup').modal('show');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply reset your form when the Bootstrap modal window is closed.

```
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
    $(this).find('form')[0].reset();
});
```